# Creating a typeclass in Haskell but getting "ambiguos occurence" error

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, typeclass

I'm new to Haskell and currently trying to figure out how to write my own typeclasses. This is what I've got so far:

```
data Signal = X | O

class Show a where
    show :: a -> String
instance Show Signal where
    show X = "X"
    show O = "O"
```

And when I try this out I get an error :

```
Ambiguous occurrence `Show'
    It could refer to
       either `Prelude.Show',
       or `Main.Show
```

And I can't figure out why that is because I thought the whole point of typeclasses in Haskell was that it made overloading of functions possible? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Yes, but you should not define the typeclass in your module.

Comment: Then where do I define the typeclass instead?

Comment: it is already defined in the `Prelude`, you here define a second one, that is what the compiler is saying: that there are now *two* typeclasses, so it is unclear for which one you define an instance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I can't figure out why that is because I thought the whole point of typeclasses in Haskell was that it made overloading of functions possible?

That is correct, but you here define a *new* typeclass `Show` that is clashing with the one in the `Prelude`.

If you define an instance, then it is ambiguous to which `Show` typeclass it is referring. To the one defined in the `Prelude` (where al lot of types are members of), or the one you defined in your own program.

You thus can define this as:

```
data Signal = X | O

-- no definition for Show

instance Show Signal where
    show X = "X"
    show O = "O"
```

If you want to define your own typeclass, you can work with:

```
import Prelude hiding (Show)

data Signal = X | O

class Show a where
    show :: a -> String

instance Show Signal where
    show X = "X"
    show O = "O"
```

but that is probably *not* a good idea, since all the other types are no member of the new typeclass, only a member of the one defined in the `Prelude`.

A typeclass can thus be seen as an interface in languages like Java: your data types can be members of a typeclass if they define an instance that thus defines the implementation of the methods (here `show`). But if two interfaces have the same name, that does *not* mean that these are the same interface.

Comment: Is there any way I can overwrite the Show typleclass from Prelude?

Comment: @Rosarosa: you can `import Prelude hiding (Show)`, this will prevent loading the `Show` typeclass, and thus the you can define your own.

Comment: @Rosarosa: the idea is that you define multiple *instances* for a typeclass, not multiple typeclasses that have the same name.